# Проблема с горизонтальной прокруткой в Google Chrome

Tags: вёрстка, google-chrome, прокрутка

Всем привет! В процессе верстки время от времени, естественно, допускаются ошибки, недочеты, вследствие которых появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Проблема в том, что появляется (или исчезает) она не сразу после внесения изменений и перезагрузки страницы в Google Chrome, а ТОЛЬКО после остановки и повторного запуска Live Server. Из-за этого поздно замечаешь, что что-то пошло не так. На сколько я помню, раньше такого не было — прокрутка появлялась/исчезала сразу же после изменений. Подскажите, кто в курсе, как можно это исправить, а то пока я это заметил, полдня потратил на поиск уже несуществующих ошибок. Да и вообще каждый раз останавливать и перезапускать сервер — это не серьёзно (с browser sync та же история, так что дело именно в Хроме).
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: привет, попробуйте продебажить css, пропишите в стилях *{background-color: red;}, желательно в первую строчку, чтобы первым из стилей применилось именно это и посмотрите, есть ли какой-нибудь красный объект, который имеет размер больше, чем ширина браузера

Comment: yourBadApple, так дело не в том, ошибку то я найду, только даже после её исправления приходится каждый раз перезапускать Live Server — простое обновление страницы ничего не даёт, прокрутка не пропадает. И обратно, когда проскакивает ошибка с размерами, прокрутка тоже сразу не появляется и её легко не заметить. Вот так поработаешь часик — вроде всё нормально, однако при перезапуске сервера (не страницы) появляется прокрутка и приходится шерстить всю проделанную работу, исправлять и по-новой перезапускать сервер. Вот в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Оказывается, глючат инструменты разработки в режиме эмуляции мобильных устройств. Достаточно в два клика отключить и обратно включить "мобильный режим", и всё начинает отображаться адекватно. Правда всё равно нужно это делать после каждой манипуляции с горизонтальным скролом, однако же это проще и быстрее, нежели каждый раз перезапускать серевер.